# My location on Google Maps for Android API v2 - Rotate MapView while walking

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation, userlocation, bearing

I am trying to figure out the best way to auto rotate the Google Map View so the user sees where he walks/drives.

Weirdly the small "my location" dot always shows a arrow and sets it to the right direction, but how do I get this rotation and rotate the map according to the users view direction?

This is not the first time this Question is asked, but there seems to be now solution that's really working without any problems like the implementation from the real Google Maps app (the my location button has different functionality)

Answer (score -1):

I am under the impression that the real time navigation is explicitly prohibited by the Terms of Service of Google Maps API. The section 10.4 c (iii) says

> **No navigation.** You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_4

It looks like the only allowed option is opening an intent for native Map app and it might be done with Google Maps URLs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

Comment: OP doesn't even mention building real-time navigation or route guidance... I actually have the same problem. I'm building a fitness tracker and I need to rotate the map in real-time as the user moves.

Comment: Seriously, `... so the user sees where he walks/drives` is not a real-time navigation?

Comment: Yeah, seriously. It's not route guidance and it's not against the TOS. If showing the user's current location, heading, and path traversed is against the TOS, then we wouldn't have apps like MapMyRun, RunKeeper, or Nike Run Club on the app store.